# pl/sql get all structure tables on oracle

Tags: oracle, list, plsql

I have problem about how to get all of list structure table using loop pl/sql,

i have syntax loop like bellow :

```
 BEGIN 
             FOR x IN (SELECT table_name FROM user_tables) 
                LOOP
                      EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'DESC' || x.table_name;
                END LOOP; 
             COMMIT; 
END;
```

and this is log output from sql developer

```
Error starting at line 14 in command:
BEGIN 
             FOR x IN (SELECT table_name FROM user_tables) 
                LOOP
                      EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'DESC' || x.table_name;
                END LOOP; 
             COMMIT; 
END;
Error report:
ORA-00900: invalid SQL statement
ORA-06512: at line 4
00900. 00000 -  "invalid SQL statement"
*Cause:    
*Action:
```

Help me to solve this

Thanks

Comment: How to get a list of all tables in psql: http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/1285/how-do-i-list-all-databases-and-tables-with-psql-command-line-tool/

Answer (score 2):

The `DESC` command is neither SQL nor plsql but a sqlplus command, so you can't use it in a plsql code.
More than that, why ? you can get all the values you need from [USER_TAB_COLUMNS](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28320/statviews_2091.htm#I1020277) ...
Use `DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line()` instead:

```
BEGIN 
             FOR x IN (SELECT COLUMN_NAME, DATA_TYPE, NULLABLE FROM USER_TAB_COLUMNS) 
                LOOP
                      DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line(COLUMN_NAME || ' ' || DATA_TYPE || ' ' || NULLABLE );
                END LOOP; 
             COMMIT; 
END;
```

Of course this can be formatted nicer and there are more columns you can select ...

Answer (score 0):

Consider this instead:

`Select * from All_tab_Cols` 
or to be closer to what is returned from describe:

```
Select Owner, Table_name, ColumN_Name, Data_Type, Data_Length, Nullable 
from all_tab_Cols;
```

To address your specific problem shouldn't it be:

```
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'DESC ' || x.table_name|| ';';
```

Missing space between desc & table name and ; is part of the SQL to run isn't it?

Comment: When using `execute immediate` you include the semicolon for PL/SQL and exclude it for SQL. However, as `DESC` is neither that's somewhat irrelevant.

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to reverse engineer the schema then use the DBMS_Metadata package to do so, as it can also extract constraints, privileges, users etc.